# Git, What is the recommended applying bug changes in a older commit

Tags: git

I have a code public repository with the following structure, new features are implemented by breaking off a new branch from master and merging it back.

```
   (bugfix)
      |
      U
     /          (master)
    /              |
A--B--C--D--E...J--K
   |
 (production)
```

Lets say there is a bug in the commit which production is pointing to (B).

1. What is the recommended/best way(s) to apply the bug fix to Production in Git?
2. Is it possible to apply the bugfix(U) to later features/ commits (C, D, E and so on), if so what recommended way(s) on doing it?

```
                           (master)
                              |
A---B---C'---D'---E' ... J'---K' 
    |
(production)
```

3. Is it possible to have the commit C point to U ?

```
     (bugfix)              (master)
        |                     |
A---B---U---C---D---E ... J---K 
    |
(production)
```

if so how do i have the changes applied to C, D, E ..

```
     (bugfix)                  (master)
        |                         |
A---B---U---C'---D'---E' ... J'---K' 
    |
(production)
```

**Edits**

1. Clarifying the question

   - I don't want to merge (U) to master, lets say this is because I don't want (K) to be in production yet
   - I will be moving production from C, D, E... to K not directly to K

Comment: The simplest way to apply it to master is to just cherry-pick it on top of master (i.e. it will live after `K`). Is there a specific reason you don't want to do that? Do you need `D` itself to exist *with* the bugfix or is it good enough if the latest commit on `master` has the fix? While it is possible to do what you suggest, it requires rewriting the history of master, which is a very bad idea, especially for a public repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I highly recommend to use online git playground to emulate your process, those emulators include: https://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git/#free (disclaimer: I'm not the developer of this site)

Visualized Demo:[image: this process visual demo]

Firstly, I think those things could only happened with bad branch management.

If you don't want `K` to be in production yet, why would you merge/commit `K` into the `master` branch.

To deal with this issue, you can

1. Checkout and make a new branch(`dev`) just like current `master` branch
2. Back to master branch, and reset head on `B`
3. Cherry-pick `U` onto `master` branch
4. Merge/Rebase your new `master` into your `dev` branch.
5. Finally, it may looks like:

```
     (bugfix, master)
        |
A---B---U
    |
(production)
```

```
                          (possible merge request commit, dev)
                              |
A---B---C---D---E ... J---K---L
    |
(production)
```